# how to evenly distribute total number of values between keys

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

how to evenly distribute total number of values between keys.

I am trying to evenly distribute the values to the keys. I don't want values vcn[01-05] and vcn[06-10] to come under key vsn01 and vsn02 respectively. Instead i want something like vcn[01,03,05,07,09] and vcn[02,04,06,08,10] to come under key vsn01 and vsn02 respectively.

**For Example**

**number of values:-**

```
vcn01
vcn02
vcn03
vcn04
vcn05
vcn06
vcn07
vcn08
vcn09
vcn10
```

keys

```
vsn01
vsn02
```

**Desired output**

```
vsn01

vcn01
vcn03
vcn05
vcn07
vcn09

vsn02

vcn02
vcn04
vcn06
vcn08
vcn10
```

**Note:-**

> Total number of keys - 20 i.e vsn[01-20]
>
> Total number of values - 100 i.e vcn[01-100]

Tried:-

```
#! /bin/bash


function create_vsn_vcn_lists ()
{
    pnode_cnt=$1
    vcn_cnt=$2

    declare -a vcn_lists
    for i in `seq $pnode_cnt`; do
        ${vcn_lists[${i}]}=''
    done

    for i in `seq $vcn_cnt`; do
        for j in `seq $pnode_cnt`; do
            ret=`expr ${i} % ${j}`
            if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
                ${vcn_lists[${j}]}="${vcn_lists[${j}]} vcn${i}"
            fi
        done
    done

    for i in `seq $pnode_cnt`; do
        echo ${vcn_lists[${j}]}
    done

}

create_vsn_vcn_lists 2 20
```

Comment: You mean you want to distribute like even/odd method to 01 and 02? how about if there is 03, 04 05? what output we should get at that time?

Comment: not really, in-case upon scaling I have vsn - 3 Nos i.e vsn01,vsn02,vsn03 and total values -15 Nos i.e vcn[01-15] then 

vsn01 -

vcn01
vcn04
vcn07
vcn10
vcn13

vsn02 -

vcn02
vcn05
vcn08
vcn11
vcn14

vsn03 -

vcn03
vcn06
vcn09
vcn12
vcn15

Comment: What did you try for yourself? @user3742796

Comment: @Inian update the question, couldn't get it right !

Comment: @user3742796, kindly check my answer once and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for **some** of the reasons you should not be attempting to manipulate text like this in shell. The guys who wrote shell also wrote awk for shell to call to manipulate text so just use that.

If your input is just 2 numbers as it appears from the script you posted (`create_vsn_vcn_lists`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        printf "vsn%02d\n\n", keyNr
        for (valNr=keyNr; valNr<=numVals; valNr+=numKeys) {
            printf "vcn%02d\n", valNr
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v numKeys=2 -v numVals=10 -f tst.awk
vsn01

vcn01
vcn03
vcn05
vcn07
vcn09

vsn02

vcn02
vcn04
vcn06
vcn08
vcn10
```

or if instead your input is 2 separate files as it appears from the sample input you posted (`number of values` and `keys`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    keys[++numKeys] = $0
    next
}
{
    keyNr = ((FNR-1) % numKeys) + 1
    vals[keyNr] = (keyNr in vals ? vals[keyNr] ORS : "") $0
}
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        print keys[keyNr] ORS ORS vals[keyNr] ORS
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk keys values
vsn01

vcn01
vcn03
vcn05
vcn07
vcn09

vsn02

vcn02
vcn04
vcn06
vcn08
vcn10
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v count=$(wc -l < keys) 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {b[FNR]=$0} END{for(k=1;k<=count;k++){print b[k] ORS;for(j=k;j<=i;j+=count){print a[j]};print "********"}}' number_of_values keys
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk -v count=$(wc -l < keys) '
FNR==NR{
  a[++i]=$0;
  next}
{
  b[FNR]=$0
}
END{
  for(k=1;k<=count;k++){
     print b[k] ORS;
  for(j=k;j<=i;j+=count){
     print a[j]};
     print "********"}
}
' number_of_values keys
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for code too here.

```
awk -v count=$(wc -l < keys) '  ##Creating a variable named count whose value is the number of lines in Input_file named keys.
FNR==NR{                        ##Checking condition here if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  a[++i]=$0;                    ##Creating an array named a whose index is variable i whose value is getting incremented each time with 1 and value is current line.
  next}                         ##next keyword will skip all further statements from here on wards, since we do not want to execute them now.
{
  b[FNR]=$0                     ##This statement will be executed when 2nd Input_file named keys is being read. Creating array named b whose value is $0 with index FNR.
}
END{                            ##Starting END section of awk here now.
  for(k=1;k<=count;k++){        ##Starting a for loop whose value starts from k=1 to till value of variable count.
     print b[k] ORS;            ##Printing the value of array b whose index is k and ORS whose default value is new line.
  for(j=k;j<=i;j+=count){       ##Starting a for loop here which starts from j=k to till value of variable i and increment happens with count variable increment.
     print a[j]};               ##Printing value of array a whose index is variable j.
     print "********"}          ##Printing ******** here to segregate between different output sets.
}
' number_of_values keys         ##Mentioning the Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

function create_vsn_vcn_lists {
    local vsn_cnt=$1 vcn_cnt=$2 start=1 i j
    for ((i=1; i<=vsn_cnt; ++i, ++start)); do
        printf "vsn%02d\n\n" $i
        for ((j=start; j<=vcn_cnt; j+=vsn_cnt)); do
            printf "vcn%02d\n" $j
        done
        echo
    done
}

create_vsn_vcn_lists 3 10
```

Output:

```
vsn01

vcn01
vcn04
vcn07
vcn10

vsn02

vcn02
vcn05
vcn08

vsn03

vcn03
vcn06
vcn09
```

Comment: That would literally be orders of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script as well as less portable across standard UNIX systems so what's the point?

Comment: @EdMorton That's just silly. The output will be orders of magnitude slower than your awk script, so what's the point? And it could easily be made more portable (if you are complaining about the printfs, for instance).

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you saying you don't think it will be orders of magnitude slower (it will - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice))? Are you saying we shouldn't mention that the code in question is non-portable because some other version of the code could be written that would be portable? I'm just asking what is the point of writing/using that code when an equivalent awk script would be more portable and orders of magnitude faster?

Comment: wrt timing - I just did a quick test and with 1000 vsns and 100000 vcns your shell script running `time` takes `real 0m2.225s
user 0m1.977s
sys 0m0.246s` while the first awk script in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613409/1745001) timed takes `real 0m0.078s
user 0m0.055s
sys 0m0.004s`, i.e. 2.25 secs for the shell script vs 0.078 secs for the awk script. So again - since awk's available on every standard UNIX box, whats the point of writing a non-portable shell script that'll run orders of magnitude slower?